# Replace specific words in textarea and highlight changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, split, highlight

I am working on a very large project and having to convert a lot FoxPro to C#. I am putting together a tool to help me convert the bulk of the code (that I keep find/replacing anyways) and by no means do I use it as a fix all. What I'm trying to accomplish is where a common word in FoxPro in the input textarea ("Else" for example) will be replaced with it's C#/Javascript counterpart ("} else {") and the newly converted block of code will be shown in the output textarea. So I'm creating a list of replacements:

```
var replacements = [ 
                    ["?thisform.", "@"], 
                    ["Else", "} else {"],
                    ["*--", "//"]
                ];
```

and for each first word found in the input textarea, replace with the second word and paste the entire block in the output. I have some moderately working examples in the fiddle.

```
$('#convert').click(function(){
    var input = $('#codeinput').val();

    replacements.forEach(function(pair) {
        converted = input.split(pair[0]).join(pair[1]);
    });

    //var converted = $("#codeinput").val()
                    //.replace("?thisform.", "@"); 


    // and paste final output
    $('#codeoutput').val(converted);                
});
```

**BONUS POINTS** Can we also highlight the changed words in the input and output (i understand we cannot highlight in textareas so maybe make this a div instead)?
http://jsfiddle.net/aa72vg2c/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add divs `input` and `output`, and this should do it:

```
$('#convert').click(function(){
  var input = output = $('#codeinput').val();
  for(var val in array) {
    input= input.split(val).join('<span class="high">'+val+'</span>');
    output= output.split(val).join('<span class="high">'+array[val]+'</span>');
  }
  $('#input').html('<pre>'+input+'</pre>');
  $('#output').html('<pre>'+output+'</pre>')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4su60eLm/1/

Comment: This works incredibly well for me, thank you. To further elaborate, can we color code the highlights depending of the category? http://jsfiddle.net/4su60eLm/3/

Comment: Something like an array and for statement for each category? http://jsfiddle.net/4su60eLm/4/

Comment: Sure.  I forked your fiddle and simply change `array` to `values`, `syntax`, and `db`:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lfeo08da/

Comment: You're welcome.  @Smeagol recommended using `replace` instead of `split` + `join`.  It used to be that `split` + `join` was faster, but modern browsers have optimized the `replace` function, so it's now the best method.

Answer (score 1):

You overwriting "converted" with last input replace, so only last value is replaced. And why use split join instead simple replace?
It should look like this:

```
converted = input;
replacements.forEach(function(pair) {
    converted = converted.replace(pair[0], pair[1]);
});
```

If you wanna colors you can always do something like this:

```
converted = converted.replace(pair[0], '<span class="someclass">'+pair[1]+'</span>');
```

and place it into div instead of text area.

Answer (score 1):

why not using replace as you first did?

```
var replacements = [ 
                    ["?thisform.", "@"], 
                    ["Else", "} else {"],
                    ["*--", "//"],
                    ["\n", "<br>"],
                ];


$('#convert').click(function(){
    var input = $('#codeinput').val();

    replacements.forEach(function(pair) {
        input = input.replace( pair[0], '<span class="high">'+ pair[1]+'</span>', "g");
    });

    // and paste final output
    $('#codeoutput').html(input);               
});
```

add the `g` flag to `replace` to get all occurences.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aa72vg2c/11/)

Comment: and how should i use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Global replacement would be easy task with Regexp:

```
    var replacements = [
     ["Else", "} else {"],
     ["\\*\\-\\-", "//"],
     ["\\?thisform.", "@"]
    ];

$('#convert').click(function(){
    var input = $('#codeinput').val();
    $.each(replacements, function(index, value){
     input = input.replace(new RegExp(value[0], 'g'),
              '<span class="high">'+ value[1]+'</span>');
    });
    $("#codeoutput").html(input);
});
```

And pay much attention to escape special characters for Regexp - see first array values in my example.

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aa72vg2c/13/